# What is an "algebraic tail"?

Tags: distributions, terminology, power-law

The authors of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/cond-mat/papers/0605/0605511.pdf) repeatedly use the term "algebraic tail" when describing some of the distributions they observed:

> ...the probability of remaining in a small, spatially confined region for a time T is dominated by **algebraically long tails** that attenuate the superdiffusive spread...

and

> Despite systematic deviations for short distances, all distributions show an **algebraic tail** with the same exponent $\beta \approx 0.6$, which confirms that the observed power-law is an intrinsic and universal property of dispersal.

also

> Therefore, we conclude that the slow decay in $P_0(t)$ reflects the effect of an **algebraic tail** in the distribution of rests $\phi(t)$ between displacements.

I haven't been able to find a definition of this term anywhere else.  Are they just using it as a synonym for "tail of a power law distribution", or are they referring to a particular subtype of power-law distribution, or something else entirely?

**Reference**

D. Brockmann et al., The scaling laws of human travel, [Nature 439, 462](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v439/n7075/full/nature04292.html) (2005).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this appears to be a synonym with a power-law tail behavior (i.e., decays slower than exponential). Here are some other references to this behavior:

http://www.math.columbia.edu/~chekhlov/PhysRevLetters.77.15.1996.pdf
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3136455/